# Issue with sorting date columns with the jQuery table-sorter plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I implemented the jQuery TableSorter add-on for my table and all works fine, except that specific column, which contains the following format: `HH:mm, dd.MM`, for example `09:45, 15.11` or `15:48, 16.11`.

As I have done before with this plug-in, I tried this is in the javascript file, which sorts the tables:

```
$(function() 
    $(".my-table").tablesorter({
      sortList: [[1,0]], // sorting on the second column
      dateFormat : "HH:mm, dd.MM"
    });
  });
```

However, it only sorts by the `HH:mm`, which causes wrong entries (because it ignores the dates). Is there another specific datestring that would work with this, as I can't really change it, or is there a way to write my own custom parser and implement it with the plug-in? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached a solution if anyone stumbles upon this specific date format. It turns out that the TableSorter plug-in allows for adding a custom parser, that you can suit for your needs. More information about this here - https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers.html.

In this specific case, it looked like this, which now works and the column is sortable:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'custom_date_parser',
        // Auto-detection
        is: function(date) {
            return false;
        },
        // Normalize data and allow sorting for this specific type
        format: function(date) {
            // get current year
            var current_year = new Date().getFullYear()

            // obtain date values from column
            // current format HH:mm, dd.MM
            var hour = date.slice(0, 2);
            var minutes = date.slice(3, 5);
            var day = date.slice(7, 9);
            var month = date.slice(10, 12);

            // convert to date object
            return date = new Date(current_year, month - 1, day, hour - 1, minutes)
        },
        parsed: false,
        // Type of sorting to use
        type: 'numeric'
    });

// Perform the sorting
    $("#table-name").tablesorter({
        // apply custom parser only to the second column
        headers: {
            1: {
                sorter: 'custom_date_parser'
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`dateFormat` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#dateformat) only allows 3 settings: `"mmddyyyy"` (default), `"ddmmyyyy"` and `"yyyymmdd"`.

In this case you'll need to add a [custom column parser](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#custom-parsers) - see [this demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-dates.html), but it only has an example for the Sugar.js library.

In particular, make sure to load and use [this parser](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-date.js) that includes interfaces to both Sugar.js and the Date.js library.